# Angular, al cargar dentro de la pagina otra pagina mediante ajax no me permite usar angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tengo una pagina en la que uso un framework lumx que se basa en angular, todo funciona perfecto. El problema esta en que en una de las opciones cargo un div con contenido de otra pagina mediante ajax. 
Y es en esa pagina en la cual no puedo usar el framework y tampoco angular, ya que pruebo a poner un simple boton y el evento ng-click y no funciona tampoco.

Estoy perdido y no se que hacer.

```html
<html ng-app="lumx-demo">
<head>

....

<!--  Aqui en un momento dado se carga la pagina por ajax-->
<div id="graficaEstudio">grafica estudio</div>

........

<script src="js/lumX-1.7.7/demo/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/lumX-1.7.7/demo/js/demo/layout/js/layout_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/lumX-1.7.7/demo/js/demo/main-nav/js/main-nav_directive.js"></script>
<script src="js/lumX-1.7.7/demo/js/demo/main-nav/js/main-nav-link_directive.js"></script>
<script src="js/lumX-1.7.7/demo/js/demo/component/js/component_directive.js"></script>
```

No se si el problema estara en que cargo angular antes sin la pagina que se carga por ajax y luego tengo que recargar algo.

He intentado en esa pagina que cargo por ajax a poner un ejemplo sencillo que me funciona fuera y tampoco lo coge y ni da error.

```html
<input type="button" value="carga"  ng-app="ngClickExample" ng-controller="test" ng-click="foo()">
<script>
    (function(angular) {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('ngClickExample', [])
            .controller('test', function($scope) {
                $scope.foo = function(){
                    alert('bar');
                }
            });
    })(window.angular);
</script>
```

Comment: *No se si el problema estara en que cargo angular antes sin la pagina que se carga por ajax* - **Sí**. Primero carga el `div` con AJAX y luego de eso ejecutas una IIFE con tu código angular.

Comment: sera posible usar `ng-If` + `ng-Include` ? o prueba este hilo (llama a compile) https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195167/1423096

Comment: El problema de IIFE es que cargo todo al principio y luego en una de las opciones cargo ese codigo con ajax y lo que no se es justamente que codigo angular cargar para que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes cargar una pagina por ajax, no es lo debido, el ajax se utiliza para mandar informacion y optener data tipo json, xml, etc.. si quieres mostrar la pagina redirecciona a ella

Comment: No cargo la pagina como tal, actualizo un div con contenido html. No me habre  explicado bien.